# Local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final

Tags: java

I´m trying to create a `getValue()` function from a pojo that use summatory of details class values in this sense:

```
@Transient
public BigDecimal getValue() {
   BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0);

   details.stream().forEach((detail) -> {
      sum = sum.add(detail.getValue());
   });

   return sum;
}
```

but I don't know why this the line `sum = sum.add(detail.getValue());` provoke this error:

> local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or
>   effectively final

Can you say me what's I'am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: The error message is fairly clear: The local variable (`sum`) must be `final` if you want to access it from the lambda. So you can't do this the way you've shown, and have to approach it another way.

Comment: Right, and I posted an answer saying that, but then realized it still wouldn't work because he tries to modify sum.

Comment: But if I declare the local variable `sum` like `final' then I get next error: "cannot assign a value to a final variable sum"

Comment: @axiorema Correct.  Lambdas _will not_ allow you to modify local variables like this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You *cannot* modify variables from inside a lambda.  That's just not a thing you're allowed to do.

What you *can* do here is write this method as

```
return details.stream()
    .map(Detail::getValue)
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: Oh, very interesting, I'm going to try to understand this ;) Thanks

Comment: It's a very instructive answer, I learned a lot of it. I like `map` and `reduce` functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, just do not use the lambda expression in the foreach loop

```
@Transient
public BigDecimal getValue() {
   BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0);

   for (Detail detail : details) {
      sum = sum.add(detail.getValue());
   }

   return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my way to avoid final p in the loop and it worked.

```
public void getSolutionInfo(){      
ArrayList<Node> graph = Main.graph; 

    for(int p=1;p<=Pmax;p++) {          
        final int p2=p;
        System.out.printf("number of node with priority p = %d is %d ",p, graph.stream().filter(node->node.getPriority()==p2).count()); 
    }
```