# Keeps having error when trying to return combobox value upon button click

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have a combobox and a button within my GUI.
I am trying to return the value in the combobox when user click on the button.
However the line `setOnAction`, it keeps getting highlighted with the error `local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final`

```
public class ComboBoxGui
{
    public String show(String msg)
    {
        ...
        
        ObservableList<String> opts = 
            FXCollections.observableArrayList("A", "B", "C");
        ComboBox myComboBox = new ComboBox(opts);
        Button okBtn = new Button("OK");

        ...

        String result;
        okBtn.setOnAction(evt -> {
            result = typeComboBox.getValue().toString(); // this line keeps getting highlighted
        });
    }
}
```

I tried setting `String result` to final, placing my variable `myComboBox` as a private instance or, creating a new method to derive the text value etc and it does not seems to resolve the error on hand.

Appreciate for any help rendered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493738/local-variables-referenced-from-a-lambda-expression-must-be-final)

Comment: The error tells you exactly why it won`t work "local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final". If you want to modify a variable then don't use a lambda expression.

Comment: You're trying to return a result from the `show` method, where the result is retrieved via user interaction. How is the `result` variable supposed to be assigned a value before the method returns? Interacting with the user is inherently asynchronous. Perhaps what you should be using is a `Dialog<R>` and its `showAndWait()` method. Or use something like a `CompletableFuture`. You could even start your own nested event loop (JavaFX 9+), but I caution against doing so unless you have no other choice.